# Laravel 5.2 Session not passing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple success message on store to DB.

```
\Session::flash('info', 'Success! Words created');
```

now if I var_dump the session and return that, great.

As soon as I move to another view.  Session info is gone!

I've tried all sorts, I'm on laravel 5.1.

looked into the middleware groups but i just get blank pages when adding routes in here..

Comment: This question is little unclear to me. Can you more elaborate?

Comment: I have a controller with a store method which after persisting adds a flash message above.  When redirecting to a view I cannot access the session message.   If I dump the session object in the method I can see my message.  Soon as it goes to the view, session message is gone.

Comment: Sorry my version is 5.2.* so I assume it's to do with sessions but I cannot get it to work

Comment: Please, share view code for display Session message. And `route.php` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a breaking problem with the 5.2 upgrade. What's happening is the middleware which is responsible for making that `errors` variable available to all your views is not being utilized because it was moved from the global middleware to the `web` middleware group.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. In your `kernel.php` file(app/Http/Kernel.php), you can move the `middleware \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` back to the `protected $middleware` property.
2. Wrap all your `web` routes with a route group and apply the web middleware to them:

   ```
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
       // Place all your web routes here...(Cut all `Route` which are define in `Route file`, paste here) 
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks!   Although which routes do I add to the group?  I have a route resource list giving me a myname_path  route and covers all the usual: index, store, show etc.  I tried adding the index but the page went blank....

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction.  I'll take a look at the middleware and route documentation for v5

Comment: just managed to try out your suggestions.  I placed my entire route::resource list for that specific controller into the route::group([middleware etc and it worked first time!  Awesome, thanks.